Flutter build failing with gradle error even after fixing
I've been trying to build an apk, tho working perfectly in my ios emulator.It's not building for apk and i got the error below:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
   > Compilation failed to complete, origin: /Users/mac/Documents/flutter/myvidcall/build/record_android/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/release/classes.jar:com/llfbandit/record/record/format/Format.class

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 45s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          286.5s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. │
│ Find the latest version on                                             │
│ https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update │
│ /Users/mac/Documents/flutter/myvidcall/android/build.gradle:           │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

I upgraded the gradle several times top the latest, same issue.
I tried 2.0.0 same issue and a tried a little lesser too, same issue.
below is my gradle.
...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
             // Enable shrinking, obfuscation, and code optimization for the release build
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // Add this block to exclude problematic classes from minification
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    ...


my proguard contains
-keep class com.llfbandit.record.** { *; }```

"Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin."

try this answer

This isn't a kotlin version problem. You can try with latest kotlin version and the same error will happen.
The problem is related to proguard-rules.pro file. You need to edit it. If this error is occured by some libraries like razorpay, you can get the proguard rules from their documentaation.

Clean and Rebuild the Project

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build apk

android/build.gradle:


buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
android/app/build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yourapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
Detailed Error Logs

    enter code here

flutter build apk -v

